# Foundation tabs don't work in modal when using ajax

Tags: ajax, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I took the basic tabs html at

```
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html
```

and used it as an Ajax response.

In my index.html I have the following:

```
<a href="ajax/endpoint" data-reveal-ajax="true" 
   class="button" data-reveal-id="myModal">Login</a>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>

</div>
```

The modal comes up with the tabs, but they do not work, I cannot switch between tabs.

Any clues on what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess, have you loaded all the needed css files?

Comment: Other Modal dialogs on the same index.html page which do not use ajax work fine. If I copy the tabs html and inline them into the div  #myModal, then also it works fine. Does that exclude css issues?

Comment: Posting for others who might encounter this:

The following code at the end of the html fragment that is served through ajax seems to animate the tabs.

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>

Not sure why this is needed again, it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. Its also odd that just this script is required, not the css and script references in the original index.html page. In fact if I add them all and make the snippet a complete standalone html page, then the modal misbehaves, it won't come down all the way the second time, the tabs are truncated by the top of the browser.

Answer (score 3):

I got into a similar type of problem. It was with buttons that revealed a modal. I called button via Ajax Request and when they were clicked nothing happened.

I resolved my issue using the jquery that is intended to be used at bottom of the page to activate objects after loading.

```
$(document).foundation();
```

Use this code just **after you place the responseText** in your HTML. And you would be able to switch between tabs.
Hope this would help you too. Please give a feedback about the result.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which version of Foundation you are using?

In Foundation 4 it is sections,

If you are using Sections in a Modal, or they are being loaded via AJAX, or they are hidden when Foundation is initialized, you will need to reflow the sections to get tabs to display properly:

```
   $('#myModal').on('opened', function () {
   $(this).foundation('section', 'reflow');
   });
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/components/section.html You will see the above note in the bottom of this link.

i didn't see the any note about this in foundation 5 doc http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html

Comment: I was using Foundation 5, the tabs show up, but I am not able to switch between them without the additional line mentioned in my comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem except for the part where you display your tabs in a modal. chinmayahd's answer helped my problem BTW.

I placed `$(document).foundation('reflow');` inside the `success` option when calling ajax in order for foundation to work **after** page load. Like this one,

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'your/url/here',
    success : function(data) {               // data holding HTML markup of tabs
        $('div#content').html(data);         // tabs are displayed here
        $(document).foundation('reflow');    // perform foundation reflow
    }
});
```